# How can i extract data from the XML using Pentaho when xml tag is repeating?

Tags: xml, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am extracting data from the XML . In that i have two duplicate tag with different values . So how can i get this data in different columns ?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So , i want to get those  values in different columns . How can i achieve this ? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry the Code is 

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>B</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A1</td>
  <td>B2</td>
 </tr>
</table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficult part is to make kettle to understand in which column to put the result.

1. In the `Content` panel, define the `Loop XPath` as being "/table/tr". That will make the PDI to produce on row per  tag.
2. In the `Field` panel, define a first column named "col1" with `XPath` as "td[1]", and a second column named "col2" with `XPath` "td[2]".

If the column number is dynamic, you need metadata injection.

For your info, the `repeat` checkbox is not to repeat a field, it is to instruct for Kettle to pick the value of the previous row in case a field is missing on a row.

[image]

Comment: Thanks AlainD , you really saved my day , But buddy i am facing one more issue to  , i have following xml format . In that i want to take paragraph values  so how can i achieve that .
I have tried one way that i mentioned into the comment

Comment: `<tbody>
                        
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <paragraph styleCode="cellHeader">Overview:</paragraph>
                              <paragraph>Test</paragraph>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td ID="problem29name">Anemia</td>
                           <td>07/30/2015</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>`

Comment: Here is the link : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QohXTPK-me8Di3Yfu4VI-IhhqN5Oe_r_



https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PO9wR_WVlcCuiJxpXIGWjhBFmq6EeZYj

Comment: Have you tried `loop XPath` = /tbody/tr/td and `field XPath` = paragraph[1], paragraph[2]. If yes, open a new question with the xml and what you want to see.